# how to disable or handle minimise app feature on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is it possible to handle/disable this kind of feature on Flutter app(Android - Samsung Device)?

[image: split screen is here, click here]

[image: image 1]
<sub>(source: [gadgetguideonline.com](https://cdn.gadgetguideonline.com/galaxys6/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/04/samsung_galaxy_S6_multi_window_10_launch_pop_up_view.jpg))</sub>

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a desirable feature, because it allows the user to multi-task on large screens.

In any case, if you want to disable it, put the following tag under `<application>` element of your `AndroidManifest` :

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

Refer [Multi-Window support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) for detailed guidelines.

Comment: thanks @AnkurAggarwal.. Is it also disable split screen? https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/mediumplus/public/article_images/2017/05/multi-window-galaxy-s8.jpg?itok=f1NCiV5l